# Nodejs iteration count misunderstanding

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have a set of data consisting of people with attached tables. The tables can have any number of rows. For each row I would like to print out the person and the table's row info. In the first script, I iterate a row count before writing each table line. Doing it this way, the row count is always correct per table line.

```
async.each(data.table, function(array, printCallback) {
    rowCount++;
    fs.appendFile(fileName, data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName + ',' + data.email + ',' + data.bd + ',' + key + ',' + array[0] + ',' + array[1] + ',' + array[2].slice(0, array[2].indexOf(' ')) + '\n', function(err){
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        printCallback();
    });
});
```

If I move rowCount into the callback for the appendFile() method, then the rowCount only updates with each person, not each table row of each person. So, if the first person has three rows, rowCount would be the same on each one.

```
async.each(data.table, function(array, printCallback) {


    fs.appendFile(fileName, data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName + ',' + data.email + ',' + data.bd + ',' + key + ',' + array[0] + ',' + array[1] + ',' + array[2].slice(0, array[2].indexOf(' ')) + '\n', function(err){
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        rowCount++;
        printCallback();
    });
});
```

Shouldn't fs.appendFile be blocking? And async.each limits to one row at a time, so rowCount should iterate after each row either way, bit it doesn't work this way. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.appendFile()` is not blocking, it's async.  `fs.appendFileSync()` is blocking.

`async.each()` runs operations in parallel, not one at a time, so the timing of your `rowCount` increase will be different in your two code examples.

You can use `async.eachSeries()` or `async.eachLimit()` if you want to run only one async operation at a time which you probably do here so that you can control the order things are appended to the file.

Comment: Thanks so much. This clarified a lot for me.